# Splitting a pandas dataframe across attributes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recommendation-engine

I have a dataframe that has many users and many items and user item pairs have a rating although not all users rate all items

```
userId    itemId    rating
1         1         4
1         5         3
1         2         5
2         5         2
2         4         4
```

I'm trying to test the performance of a recommender model that returns the top k items to a user based on their ratings of other items. What is the easiest way to split the dataframe so that I can make a test set of the highest rated items for some subset of users?

Comment: so to clarify, you want to select a portion of your dataset that contains/is obtained from the highest rated elements?

Comment: Welcome to SO, don't hesitate to provide an explicit desired output from your data sample.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the two highest rated items per UserId. You can change the number in `head()` and also looking into https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html as alternative

```
data='''userId    itemId    rating
1         1         4
1         5         3
1         2         5
2         5         2
2         4         4'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' \s+', engine='python')
df.sort_values('rating', ascending=False).groupby('userId').head(2)
```

Output

```
   userId  itemId  rating
2       1       2       5
0       1       1       4
4       2       4       4
3       2       5       2
```